# Is it possible to use foreach loop with amp-carousel

Tags: html, asp.net, for-loop

I want to use a foreach loop to go through an array to populate a amp-carousel in a aspx page. I want to know if this is possible with an example.
i have tried using amp-list with amp-carousel. which i understood doesn't work.

this is what i have tried

```
     <amp-list class="mx1 md-mxn1" [src]="'api/' + products.filter + '-' + products.category + '-products.json'" src= some.json height="400" width="300" layout="responsive">
<template type="amp-mustache">
   <amp-carousel height="200" layout="fixed-height" type="carousel">
   {{#Images}}
       <amp-img src="{{ImageUrl}}" layout="fixed" width="100" height="100" alt="{{AlbumName}}"></amp-img>
   {{/Images}}
   </amp-carousel>
 </template>
```

Comment: you can write a loop to generate some HTML, yes, if that's how your carousel is populated

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: Are you using MVC with Razor, or asp.net WebForms? You can look up the syntax for a for, foreach or while loop for either format online already. What have you tried?

Comment: I want to do this using server tags. I'm not able to understand how

Comment: That doesn't answer either of my questions

Comment: @ADyson I tried using amp-list which I realised doesn't work. I thought I could try using the foreach loop but I'm not able to figure out how to pass the data to the aspx page. I'm using MVC with asp.net

Comment: @JayeshBafna You mean amp-list like  https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-list ? Why didn't it work? You can make a JSON endpoint easily enough in MVC. I think you need to clarify your question. Show your carousel as it is now, and explain what data you want to fetch into it and where it is stored.

Comment: @ADyson i have updated the question with what i have tried with amp-list. 
which doesn't work with amp-carousel.
so i was considering populating the amp-carousel using server tags and for each.
my json returns an array with imageurl and other attributes. 
but i am not able to figure out how to access this through server tags on the aspx page. Thats the example i am asking for

Comment: So at the moment you are fetching the data from what appears to be a static JSON file. Is that the real source of your data? Or does it come from a database really?

Comment: It comes from a database. Just amp-list works fine. I need to get to work for amp-carousel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so you mention this data comes from a database. Let's say for example that you fetched this data from your database and used it to populate a list of C# model objects, based on a class called `AmpImage`.

The AmpImage class would look something like this:

```
public class AmpImage
{
  public string ImageURL { get; set; }
  public string AlbumName { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your controller action (the one which renders the view in which you want to display this carousel) you'd fetch your data from the database and pass it to the view. Assuming your view probably already has some other model defined, we'll add this data to the ViewBag instead, so that it's available to the Razor code in the view.

```
List<AmpImage> images = //...whatever code is needed to fetch the image records from the DB and populate the list
ViewBag.AmpImages = images;

//rest of your action method code goes here
```

Finally in the View (.cshtml file) itself, you can loop through the list of images and render the necessary HTML to display the carousel:

```
<amp-carousel height="200" layout="fixed-height" type="carousel">
    @foreach (AmpImage img in ViewBag.images) {
       <amp-img src="@img.ImageURL" layout="fixed" width="100" height="100" alt="@img.AlbumName"></amp-img>
   }
</amp-carousel>
```

Hopefully you can see how the foreach loop is created in Razor, and also how the @ symbol before variable names is used to inject values from the C# data into the HTML which gets sent to the browser.